# ptrace one thread from another

Tags: multithreading, ptrace

Experimenting with the `ptrace()` system call, I am trying to trace another thread of the same process. According to the man page, both the tracer and the tracee are specific threads (not processes), so I don't see a reason why it should not work. So far, I have tried the following:

- use `PTRACE_TRACEME` from the `clone()`d child: the call succeeds, but does not do what I want, probably because the parent of the to-be-traced thread is not the thread that called `clone()`
- use `PTRACE_ATTACH` or `PTRACE_SEIZE` from the parent thread: this always fails with `EPERM`, even if the process runs as root and with `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1)`

In all cases, `waitpid(-1, &status, __WALL)` fails with `ECHILD` (same when passing the child pid explicitly).

What should I do to make it work?

If it is not possible at all, is it by desing or a bug in the kernel (I am using version 3.8.0). In the former case, could you point me to the right bit of the documentation?

Comment: This LKML thread may be related: http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/ptrace_self_attach.html

Answer (score 4):

As @mic_e pointed out, this is a known fact about the kernel - not quite a bug, but not quite correct either. [See the kernel mailing list thread about it.](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/ptrace_self_attach.html) To provide an excerpt from Linus Torvalds:

> That "new" (last November) check isn't likely going away. It solved
>   *so* many problems (both security and stability), and considering that
>
> (a) in a year, only two people have ever even *noticed*
>
> (b) there's a work-around as per above that isn't horribly invasive
>
> I have to say that in order to actually go back to the old behaviour,
>   we'd have to have somebody who cares *deeply*, go back and check every
>   single special case, deadlock, and race.

The solution is to actually start the process that is being traced in a subprocess - you'll need to make the ptracing process be the parent of the other.

Here's an outline of doing this based on [another answer that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092189/3369324):

```
// this number is arbitrary - find a better one.
#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

int main_thread(void *ptr) {
    // do work for main thread
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *vstack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    pid_t v;
    if (clone(main_thread, vstack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_PARENT_SETTID | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_FS | CLONE_IO, NULL, &v) == -1) { // you'll want to check these flags
        perror("failed to spawn child task");
        return 3;
    }
    long ptv = ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, v, NULL, NULL);
    if (ptv == -1) {
        perror("failed monitor sieze");
        return 1;
    }
    // do actual ptrace work
}
```