# Is there a way to view the register contents of one thread from another thread within the same process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, ptrace

Let's say I have a process that contains three threads: A, B, and C.

I want to use thread A to pause thread B, examine thread B's register values/stack contents, and then feed some of that information from thread B into thread C (via thread A).

According to [this](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/ptrace_self_attach.html) post from Linus Torvalds, the `ptrace` syscall won't work here because the threads are within the same process.

Is there another way of accomplishing this?

Update: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157315/ptrace-one-thread-from-another) question discusses *why* it doesn't work; I'd like to know if a work-around exists that doesn't involve creating a child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to work around this using a signal.  Pick an otherwise unused signal, eg `SIGUSR1` and install a signal handler for it using the `sa_sigaction` member of `struct sigaction` and specifying the `SA_SIGINFO` flag.  Block the signal in every thread except the thread of interest (thread B).

When you want to examine thread B, send a thread-directed signal to it using `pthread_kill()`.  The signal handler will then fire, and its third argument will be a pointer to a `ucontext_t` structure.  The `uc_mcontext` member of this structure is a machine-dependent `mcontext_t` structure, which will contain the register values at the point that the thread was interrupted.

You then just need to devise a safe way to pass these values back to thread A.